# generating int up to 100 million throws exception

Tags: java

I am trying to generate integers up to 100 million, then combine it with pre-defined integer/string.

> Example: predefined = 1010 Generated: gen = 5020315 Combined =
>   10105020315

then save that number to .txt file, so text file should have 100 million lines.

Here is a code I wrote:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class exec{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        int initial = 6618;
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("variations.txt", "UTF-8");
        for(int a = 0; a < 100000000; a++){
            int a2 = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(initial) + Integer.toString(a));
            writer.println(a2);
        }
        writer.close();

    }

}
```

But it throws the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input
>   string: "6618100000"

Why does this happen? Where is the problem?

Comment: Where do you get the Exception? Please post the complete stacktrace

Comment: 32 bits of `int` are only good for up to 2147483648. You need a `long`.

Comment: What is the purpose of taking the constructed number and converting it back to an Integer? You could print that out as a String without issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need long , and you can use `Long.parseLong();`.
largest value for int is long 2^31-1 but for long is 2^63-1.

Answer (score 2):

Combining `6618` which the value of `a` leads to a number too large to be held in an int variable (For example, `6618100000` is too large to be held in an int variable). The largest value for int is `2^31-1`. You can use `Long.parseLong()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you are parsing, you need to make sure that the Integer you want to create from the string is smaller than Integer.MAX.

Integer.MAX is equal to 2147483647, and so any value bigger than this will cause an exception.